# Velocity of the point of contact when we are walking

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, friction

I know friction applies the forward push needed to walk (without slipping). Can we say that the point of the contact ( on the backward foot?) when we are walking will be at rest wrt the ground in much the same way the point of contact in a pure rolling is wrt the ground?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single point of contact, when walking there is multitude of points or a whole surface that makes contact with the ground. But otherwise yes, those points of the boot, if it does not slip, have zero velocity with respect to the ground.